# What is the verb surveyed following?

Tags: sentence-meaning

"Timothy Wilson {did} an experiment in which he {gave} students a choice of five different art posters, and then later {surveyed} to see if they still liked their choices." (source: A story of how success happens By David Brooks)

Is the verb surveyed connected to the verb did or gave?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the story, but I assume the whole text describes the experiment. The experiment was:

1. Give students a choice of five different art posters.
2. Later, survey to see if they still liked their choices.

So "surveyed" can be viewed as paired with "gave".

If "surveyed" is paired with "did" it means that the description of the experiment includes only giving students a choice of posters; that's not an interesting or useful experiment, so I would not interpret the sentence this way.

Answer (score 0):

The verbs **gave** and **surveyed** belong to the phrase headed by **in which**, so that **he** is the subject of both verbs:

```
Wilson did
an experiment
      in which 
        he 
          gave students a choice of five different art posters
            and then later 
          surveyed [them] to see if they still liked their choices.
```

But it is only because we understand the survey to be part of the experiment that we parse the sentence in that manner. It is largely a semantic decision not a syntactic one.  The same basic structure could have "Wilson" be the subject of **did** and **went on**:

```
 Wilson
  did
       an experiment
          in which 
            he gave students a choice of five different art posters
            asking them a week later if they still liked their choice

  and 
  then later     

  went on to win a Nobel Prize in Economics for his research into Buyer's Remorse.
```